# research statement for assistant professorship (W1, pure mathematics in Germany)

Tags: mathematics, statement-of-purpose, faculty-application, germany

What should a research statement for an application for an assistant professorship (W1, Juniorprofessor) contain (pure mathematics in Germany)? How long should it be?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the [tag:statement-of-purpose] tag. It might be useful to browse [previous questions with this tag](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statement-of-purpose?sort=votes&pageSize=50).

Comment: As far as I am aware, the term "Assistant Professor" is not one that is commonly used in Germany. On the other hand, German academic positions invariably advertise the academic grade. Can you clarify if you are asking about a W1 or W2 position or something altogether different?

Comment: Assistant Professor = Junior Professor = W1

Comment: Additionally: would answer of the form "similar to how you would write a research statement for a US postdoc / Assist Prof/ Assoc Prof position" be useful? In other words, do you include the country "Germany" because you just want to be precise, or do you actually know some things about applying in other countries and just want to translation of the German academic system to that of some other countries?

Comment: I just want to be precise.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you speak German, you could search for guidelines on the evaluation of "Juniorprofessoren" which are published by many universities ("Leitfaden zur Evaluierung von Juniorprofessuren), e.g., see here for one from the University of Magdeburg: http://www.uni-magdeburg.de/rektorat/JPLF.pdf. In such guidelines, you will often find at least information on the content, see point 4.5 in the linked document.